# Convert delimiter

Tags: sql-server-express

I'm using SQL Server Express 2005 and I would like to convert columns and decimal delimiters:

```
Use StockDataFromSella;
DECLARE @D1 DateTime 
DECLARE @D2 DateTime 
DECLARE @Interval FLOAT 

SET @D1  = '2009-09-21T09:00:00.000' 
SET @D2  = '2010-10-20T17:30:00.000'
SET @Interval = 15 

;WITH  
L0 AS (SELECT 1 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 1), 
L1 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 A CROSS JOIN L0 B), 
L2 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 A CROSS JOIN L1 B), 
L3 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 A CROSS JOIN L2 B), 
L4 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 A CROSS JOIN L3 B), 
Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS i FROM L4), 
Ranges AS( 
SELECT  
      DATEADD(MINUTE,@Interval*(i-1),@D1) AS StartRange, 
      DATEADD(MINUTE,@Interval*i,@D1) AS NextRange 
FROM Nums where i <= 1+CEILING(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@D1,@D2)/@Interval)) 
,cte AS ( 
SELECT  
     *  
     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Simbolo,r.StartRange ORDER BY [DataOra])      AS RN_ASC  
     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Simbolo,r.StartRange ORDER BY [DataOra] DESC) AS RN_DESC 
FROM Ranges r 
JOIN dbo.tbl1MinENI p  ON p.[DataOra] >= r.StartRange and p.[DataOra] < r.NextRange ) 
SELECT  

      CONVERT(VARCHAR, MAX(CASE WHEN RN_ASC=1 THEN [DataOra] END), 103) AS DataOraDate, 
      CONVERT(CHAR(5), MAX(CASE WHEN RN_ASC=1 THEN [DataOra] END), 108) AS DataOraTime,     
      MAX(CASE WHEN RN_ASC=1 THEN [DataOra] END) AS DataOra, 
      MAX(CASE WHEN RN_ASC=1 THEN [Apertura] END) AS [Apertura], 
      MAX(Massimo) Massimo, 
      MIN(Minimo)  Minimo, 
      MAX(CASE WHEN RN_DESC=1 THEN [Chiusura] END) AS [Chiusura],
      SUM(Volume) Volume
      /*MAX(CASE WHEN RN_DESC=1 THEN [DataOra] END) AS ChiusuraDataOra*/
FROM cte 
GROUP BY Simbolo,StartRange
ORDER BY DataOra
```

When execute the query, copy and paste in a txt file will give ';' as column separator while I need ',' and I get ',' for decimals where I need '.'

Is there also a way to remove ':' in DataOraTime column?

Thanks! Alberto

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste of the result has nothing to do with the query but with the program you execute the query in, because that program is responsible for formatting the result into a format that can be copied to the clipboard.

To change the date and time format you will most likely change some session variables before executing the statement.

Comment: Is there a way to print Time column result in 0930 format instead of 09:30 as of now? I don't need this ':' between hours and minutes. Thanks